# QSlider: setting the color on hover

Tags: qt

With the stylesheet below the goal is to customize the QSlider so both slider handle and the groove horizontal slide line are yellow when the mouse is hovering over the slider. For some reason I can only make slider handle to turn yellow but attempting to color the groove hides the slider handle. How can this be fixed?

[image: QSlider styled with the stylesheet]

```
        "QSlider {"
            "background-color: #FF3B3B3B;"
            "color: white;"
            "border : 0.1em;"
            "height:  1.5em;"
        "}"
        "QSlider::handle:vertical {"
            "height: 0.5em;"
        "}"
        "QSlider::groove:horizontal {"
            "height:  0 -0.7em;"
        "}"
        "QSlider:hover {"
            "border-color: yellow;"
            "background: #FF5A5A5A;"
        "}"
```

Change #1, add this style:

```
        "QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover {"
            "border: 4px solid #444;"
            "border-color: yellow;"
            "background: #FF5A5A5A;"
        "}"
```

Change #2, add this style:

```
        "QSlider::groove:horizontal:hover {"
            "border: 2px solid #444;"
            "border-color: yellow;"
        "}"
```

Comment: Did you revert change 1 before adding change 2?

Comment: @arc_lupus Second was added to first/